# Storing fresh wheat noodles

Tags: storage-method, storage-lifetime, noodles, wheat

What is the best way to store wheat based noodles with no eggs like fresh udon noodles? Can you just leave it in a plastic sealed container in the fridge? How long will it last for sealed in the fridge?